# why a symbol in textbox has a different ascii value from ascii table

Tags: vb.net

Why a symbol in textbox has a different ascii value from ascii table?
For example i have this symbol `‰` (DEC from ASCII table = 137) in a
 textbox and i try to get Bytes from textbox using this code:

```
Dim array() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textbox.text)
```

and i show it in console

```
 Console.WriteLine(array(0))
```

the result is "48", it should be 137 from ASCII table.

can anyone tell me what happened in there?

Comment: 48 = question mark ("?")

Comment: ASCII characters values use seven bits, so they only go up to 127. As `ASCII.GetBytes` is strict about that, it uses a question mark for an error character.

Comment: [ASCII](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii(v=vs.110).aspx) is a 7 bit encoding that doesn't include that character, so `GetBytes` returns the fallback character (should be 0x3F "?").  You could try `System.Text.Encoding.Default` instead, which will be your system's ANSI code page, or use a specific single-byte code page.

Comment: ASCII isn't what you think it is. Most of the time when people say "ASCII," they mean something else. It's great to be specific but it is not so great to be wrong. The `Text` property is of type `String`. A string in .NET is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units, one or two of which encode a Unicode [codepoint](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html). (Similarly, for Java, JavaScript, XML, HTML, …). [There is no ASCII table with ‰; It's something other than ASCII.]

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do the more preferred method of using the 'Asc()' to get the ASCII reference:

Example:

```
Sub Main()
    'Representations from ASCII Table http://www.asciitable.com/
    Dim perMile = Chr(137)

    'Write it out as char array to prove it works
    Console.WriteLine($"{perMile}")

    'tell me the numbers I used dynamically
    Dim perAsc = Asc(perMile)
    Dim array() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(perMile)

    Console.WriteLine($"{perAsc} {array(0)}")

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```